combining two dataframes
I have several pairs of tables (dataframes) and for each pair of tables I would like to combine the two so that the new table has the same dimensions as its paired predecessor, but the values in each cell are combined and the second value is listed in parentheses (val1 (val2)). To better explain...
Here is an example of one pair of tables...
              0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8    
  b       29806  5704  1594   600  1004   427   634   157    14   
  c       30720  9294   652  2027   366   623    52    26   270  
  n       37817 11238  4265  1095  2389   616   259   141    27   
  r       30422  8578  1212  1545  1023   872   108   154     7    
     
              0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8    
  b       0.746 0.143 0.040 0.015 0.025 0.011 0.016 0.004 0.000
  c       0.698 0.211 0.015 0.046 0.008 0.014 0.001 0.001 0.006
  n       0.654 0.194 0.074 0.019 0.041 0.011 0.004 0.002 0.000
  r       0.693 0.195 0.028 0.035 0.023 0.020 0.002 0.004 0.000

Here is a partial example of the desired (combined) table.
                0             1            2     3     4     5     6     7     8    
  b       29806 (0.746)  5704  (0.143)  ...  
  c       30720 (0.698)  9294  (0.211)  ...  
  n       37817 (0.654)  11238 (0.194)  ...   
  r       30422 (0.693)  8578  (0.195)  ...   

Depending on the run, there can be hundreds of paired tables as output. The paired tables will always have the same dimensions. However, the number of columns will vary across the output tables, and I won't know this information in advance. As a minor note, the number of rows will also vary depending on the run, but will be the same for all output tables (paired or not). How can I do this dynamically?
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Try combined_df = df1.astype(str) + ' (' + df2.astype(str) + ')', I don't know, how it will react when the number of columns is different.

@Epidermis  thank you for the comment....astype is for python/pandas???

Yeah astype

That is possible using matrix() and paste0(), but transfers the numbers to a non-calculable character format.
f = \(X, Y) {
  stopifnot(all.equal(dim(X), dim(Y)))
  X = as.matrix(X)
  Y = as.matrix(Y)
  matrix(paste0(X, " (", Y, ")"), nrow = nrow(X), dimnames = dimnames(X))
}

giving
> f(X, Y)
  X0              X1              X2             X3             X4             X5           
b "29806 (0.746)" "5704 (0.143)"  "1594 (0.04)"  "600 (0.015)"  "1004 (0.025)" "427 (0.011)"
c "30720 (0.698)" "9294 (0.211)"  "652 (0.015)"  "2027 (0.046)" "366 (0.008)"  "623 (0.014)"
n "37817 (0.654)" "11238 (0.194)" "4265 (0.074)" "1095 (0.019)" "2389 (0.041)" "616 (0.011)"
r "30422 (0.693)" "8578 (0.195)"  "1212 (0.028)" "1545 (0.035)" "1023 (0.023)" "872 (0.02)" 
  X6            X7            X8           
b "634 (0.016)" "157 (0.004)" "14 (0)"     
c "52 (0.001)"  "26 (0.001)"  "270 (0.006)"
n "259 (0.004)" "141 (0.002)" "27 (0)"     
r "108 (0.002)" "154 (0.004)" "7 (0)"   

where X and Y are your data frames of same dimension. Note that the output is a matrix. You might want to do as.data.frame() to coerce. Why do you want to do this?

"Meaningless". The paired tables represent the number of cells & their proportions by cluster for a particular integration, normalization, & resolution of a single cell (seurat) object that may have multiple normalization & integration methods, & resolutions therein. The combined tables (sans parentheses & additionally manipulated) are dynamically loaded along with UMAP images in a Shiny app to help understand the data & aid in choosing a clustering schema. It does not matter if the combined output is a character format, it relays information to the PI. Appreciate the answer, not the attitude.

FWIW, I took the comment in the sense that R matrices are typically used for calculation instead of display or data transfer. Absent a custom parser (which it sounds you have already created), the output would be harder to work with than either of the inputs, going from calculable numeric form to a character format that can't be directly computed upon. I think it's reasonable for someone answering a question to inquire about the context, especially when the requested approach sounds like a potential XY problem. Maybe "idiosyncratic" or "proprietary" or "non-calculable" would be better words.

@JonSpring, thank you. Changed to the speaking "non-calculable".
